# Getting error while fetching external id type field

Tags: soql, externalid

When i am trying to fetch external Id type field through soql.it is giving me error saying this column doesn't not exist on object if you are using custom field try to append __c .when it exists and it is being updated just not able to fetch it.

Is there a different way to fetch external id.

Comment: welcome to sfse - please see [ask] on getting the most from the Community

Comment: Check `Field Level Security`.